# Ruby - Most frequent words or phrases in a large set of sentences

Tags: ruby, postgresql

I want to find the most repeated words and phrases in a large set of sentences. What I was thinking is the following solution:

1. Build a hash with counts of every single word, couples and threesomes of words.
2. Give singles a weight of 1, couples with weight of 2 and threesomes with a weight of 3 (The purpose of the weight is to give priority to phrases rather than single words).
3. pick the top words/phrases from the hash.

My concern for this is when I have a large set of sentences (lets say 100K sentences with an average of 100 words in each), the hash will be huge and kill my servers memory.

Of-course I will also need to clean prepositions words like: "is", "a", "to"....

Any thoughts? My database is postgres if that helps.

Implemented the solution mentioned above:

```
  def most_common_words_or_phrases
    singles = Hash.new(0)
    doubles = Hash.new(0)
    triplets = Hash.new(0)

    reviews.find_each do |review|
      next if review.content.empty?
      parts = review.content.split.map!(&:downcase)
      size = parts.size

      parts.each_with_index do |val, index|
        next if @@prepositions.include?(val)
        second_word = parts[index + 1] if index != size - 1
        second_word = nil if second_word.present? && (val[val.size - 1] == "." || val[val.size - 1] == "," || val[val.size - 1] == "!" || @@prepositions.include?(second_word))
        third_word = parts[index + 2] if index < size - 2
        third_word = third_word.gsub(/\p{^Alnum}/, '') if third_word.present?
        third_word = nil if second_word.blank? ||(third_word.present? &&
            (second_word[second_word.size - 1] == "." || second_word[second_word.size - 1] == "," ||
                second_word[second_word.size - 1] == "!") || @@prepositions.include?(third_word))

        singles[val] += 1

        double = val + " " + second_word.gsub(/\p{^Alnum}/, '') if second_word.present?
        doubles[double] += 2 if double.present?

        triplets[double + " " + third_word] += 3 if double.present? && third_word.present?
      end
    end

    singles.merge(doubles).merge(triplets)
  end
```

Comment: For such task you may use some `key-value` storage like Redis.

Comment: And what about verb forms? Mis-speeled words (pun intended)? Proper nouns? 1 vs one? This is no mean task. You are probably better off identifying a way of doing this (instead of "thinking" about a potential solution) and then figure out how to implement said way into Ruby/PG.

Comment: Can you provide a set of sentences and required result? You mentioned you need to avoid prepositions, but wouldn't the phrases contain them? Imagine a word group `this is repeating`? Do you want to count it as a highly frequent phrase or a 3 independent words that are frequent?

Comment: @JikkuJose I think you are right. I need to clean out prepositions only for the couples and not for the triplets.

Answer (score 0):

As @bronislav mentioned in the comment, it is good to use Redis for storing bug Hashes.

But, maybe the hash would not be such huge? Remember the words are repeating the the files, so when you'll be iterating the source you need to add to the hash only the new words. Use a Hash with default value of 0:

```
irb(main):001:0> words=Hash.new(0)
irb(main):003:0> words['cucumber']
=> 0
irb(main):004:0> words['cucumber'] += 1   # found new word
=> 1
irb(main):005:0> words['cucumber'] += 1   # word was already there
=> 2
```

But the pairs and triples of words would be much more, so you may still want to use Redis.

In your case it would be good to *stem* the words before adding it to the dictionary. *Stemming* is getting the root of the word, so you can easy pair the abbreviations. For example, it would be good to treat the words: run, runs, running as one. I strongly recommend the [treat gem](https://github.com/louismullie/treat) for this (and not only for this, treat is a great Natural Language Processing library):

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'treat'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> 'run'.stem
=> "run"
irb(main):003:0> 'runs'.stem
=> "run"
irb(main):004:0> 'running'.stem
=> "run"
```

To clean prepositions like 'at', 'to', etc, use the list of english *stop words*. You can find it [here](http://www.ranks.nl/stopwords).

Comment: nice one with the stems and prepositions list!